# An efficient way to store and locate arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a collection of arrays of the form,

```
a = [1 2 3 5 6 8 9 10]
b = [1 2 3 4 7 14]
c = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 15 19 20]
```

That is, each one is a collection of non-repeating numbers from 1 to M (say M is 20 for the example, could be much larger in practice though). In general, I will have many such arrays (many more than 3, but I don't know before-hand exactly how many, likely on the order of 5000-10000) with duplicates (that is, array b may show up multiple times).

**Objective:** I want to store the arrays in some object, call it X, that keeps track of how many instances of each array it includes. Furthermore, when faced with a new array, we should be able to search X and increment the count of that array in the object, or if it is not in the array, add it to the object (with a count of 1).

**Question:** What is an efficient way to achieve the objective in Matlab?

---

**What I've tried so far:**

I was thinking about converting the arrays to logical arrays, for example,

```
a = [1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

then maybe converting the above to a binary number a_bin and to index a cell array X that stores the number, that is, X{a_bin} stores the number of times a has appeared. This seems to scale poorly though since a_bin can get very large for large M.

Comment: This sound like an XY problem to me. Why do you end up with so many arrays of different length, that you need to keep in memory all the time? I don't see the advantage.

Comment: @Bernhard I don't see why it's an issue. Shouldn't one state what they have tried rather than just asking a question? Also, I don't see why I need to justify the reason why I'm trying to do what is asked.

Comment: My point is better conveyed in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I am not saying that this is the case for you, but it looks a lot like it,

Comment: @Bernhard Thank you, I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use cell array to keep them in one place, and just search (= compare with each) if this new array is already in the main cell array. No need to complicate. Mark each element of cell array with array of positions where it is already present in the main cell array. And on new duplicate, update all of them.

Anyway, have you estimated memory use? 20 elements/array * 10k arrays * 8B/element = 2MB. This is small.

Comment: Thank you, in reality M can be much larger than 20. What is the upper limit on M for which this approach remains feasible?

Comment: @jonem If you hit memory limits you will need to work around in different ways, from writing parts of array to disk to thinking how to compress your integers in the best way possible.
But this approach should be mostly viable as long as you have enough memory. If you have 16GB, say 1k elements/array * 1M arrays = 8GB would be still ok.

Unless search becomes the bottleneck.